# PHP to redirect URL to its mobile version

Tags: php, redirect, mobile

I am having a deals site and there are many deals. I want that if anyone opens a deal page in mobile so it redirect to mobile site.

EXAMPLE:-

User Comes to This URL In Mobile - `http://www.onlinedealsindia.in/deal/buy-vitel-105-dual-sim-mobile-rs-577-from-askmebazaar-dealid598`

Than it redirects to - `http://m.onlinedealsindia.in/deal/buy-vitel-105-dual-sim-mobile-rs-577-from-askmebazaar-dealid598`

This "/buy-vitel-105-dual-sim-mobile-rs-577-from-askmebazaar-dealid598" is slug. I am calling it slug. By htaccess i made it looks like this.

Below code i am using:-

```
<?php
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/Mobile_Detect.php');
$objMobile = new Mobile_Detect;

if($objMobile ->isMobile()) {
$slug = $_GET[slug];
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'http://m.onlinedealsindia.in/deal/" .$slug. "';
}
?>
```

Any help will be appreciable and for working one i have a gift..

Comment: What is inside `Mobile_Detect.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($objMobile ->isMobile()) {
    header("Location: http://m.onlinedealsindia.in/".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
}
```

This sends a "Location" redirect header to "m.onlinedealsindia.in", keeping the requested path the same.

Comment: @Rahul No problem. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `header` and `location` to redirect visitor.

Try

```
if($objMobile ->isMobile())
{
    $slug = $_GET[slug];
    header("Location: http://m.onlinedealsindia.in/".$slug);
}
```